# Building a complete list in excel, by matching items from one cell found in another tab (extract)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula that will give me a full list of items if a cell contains an exact match from another cell in an extract (in another tab). For example, I have two tabs of data: Data A and Data B (the full exhaustive list of server names). In Data A, I have a column "M:Source Cluster" which contains the names of servers, but the tricky part is that some cells have multiple server names separated by a semicolon (`;`). Is there a way to match/index/search the cells in Column "M:Source Cluster" for each server name; and if they appear in Data B to return the name of the server names row by row into Column Z (Matching Server Names)? **I do not want to split/delimit the cell contents into columns. Picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below `MATCH` formula i column Z,

`=MATCH("*"&A1&"*",E:E,0)`

provided the value you are trying to match (A1 of other tab) contains only one string. Add an `INDEX` as per your needs.